Reference for PDEs from system of SDEs
I'm working with a system of SDEs
\begin{align*}
dX_t &= b(X_t, t) + \sigma dB_t\\
dY_t &= c(X_t, Y_t, t) + \sigma dB_t.
\end{align*}
Here, the Brownian motion is the same.
I know that classically for a singular SDE, we can adopt a PDE perspective via the Fokker-Planck equation, but I'm looking for a reference for the case where there's a coupled system of equations.

This is just a multidimensional SDE. Look for higher dimensional Fokker-Planck

@user479223 I think the main novelty is that the Brownian motion is the same in both the first and second equations. This would likely still be covered by the classical theory though (eg.. the fantastic book Stochastic Calculus by Baldi), but we could get some more interesting structural results maybe.
